# How to guarantee all data is inserted into table in same transaction?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a insert query that looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO Data1 (column1, column2)
SELECT column1, column2 FROM Data2
```

This query takes about 30 secs. Within that 30 secs someone might insert, delete, or modify data in Data2 table while the query is still running. How can I either prevent that or include changes within same transaction?

Comment: A single insert statement should take place in a single transaction.

Comment: I believe while a table is being modified it has exclusive access to it, all other requests will be queued until that `INSERT` is complete. Maybe you want to do multiple queries, in that case, you answered your own question, use transactions.

Comment: @Havenard I just tedted this. Unfortunetly, this is not the case. I just tries inserting multiple records but did not commit the transaction. Then I inserted a record in Data2. The data was inserted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way to take a exclusive lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13435997/correct-way-to-take-a-exclusive-lock)

Answer (score 0):

Modify your Query WITH(NOLOCK)
USE this

```
INSERT INTO Data1 (column1, column2)
SELECT column1, column2 FROM Data2 WITH(NOLOCK)
```

this will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to be absolutely certain to have to data changes are made during the insert, you can use the TABLOCKX query hint...

```
INSERT INTO Data1 WITH (TABLOCKX) (column1, column2)
SELECT column1, column2 FROM Data2 WITH (TABLOCKX);
```

This will give you exclusive locks on both tables until the transaction completes.