# SQL Server Lock the Row the Read and Update not working in Python

Tags: python, sql-server, concurrency, locking

I need to lock a row, read and then update a field of this row in SQL Server and Python, for a program that can run multiple process at the same time, to avoid a race condition.

I'm using the following code, but in Python it updates one Id (i.e 3411) and returns another Id (i.e. 3071). If I run the same SQL code directly in SSMS, it updates and returns the same Id.

```
import pyodbc

def read_and_update_files_queue(self):
    conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                    'Server='+self.server+';'
                    'Database='+self.database+';'
                    'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    sql_query=f'''
                BEGIN TRANSACTION;
                    DECLARE @Temp_ID AS INT
                    SELECT TOP 1 @Temp_ID=Id 
                    FROM dbo.[Queue] 
                    WITH(XLOCK, ROWLOCK)
                    WHERE [BQ_status] IS NULL and upload_date IS NOT NULL

                    Select TOP 1 
                    Id,GCS_path,file_first_upload 
                    FROM dbo.[Queue]
                    WITH(XLOCK, ROWLOCK) 
                    WHERE Id=@Temp_ID


                    UPDATE dbo.[Queue] SET BQ_status='Loading' 
                    WHERE Id=@Temp_ID

                COMMIT TRANSACTION;
                '''
    cursor.execute(sql_query)
    cursor.commit()
```

What is wrong?
The code is based on this:
[In SQL Server, how can I lock a single row in a way similar to Oracle's "SELECT FOR UPDATE WAIT"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502273/in-sql-server-how-can-i-lock-a-single-row-in-a-way-similar-to-oracles-select)
Thanks!!

Comment: Do yourself a huge favor and to this transaction inside a stored procedure on the SQLSERVER with a TRY CATCH WITH A ROLLBACK. Also What are you accomplishing with eh second select statement?

Comment: In the seconds statements I need to returns not only the ID, but also the fields called GCS_path,file_first_upload, that are used later in the python program. Why is it needed the try catch? (If I run this transaction when no ID doesnt exists, it works as expected (it does nothing) )

Comment: Then do that with your First select statement.  Just declare variables for GCS_path,file_first_upload and capture the values there to reuse later in the python program. Eliminate the second select statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the first two statements are not modifying data, [you **need** the `UPDLOCK` hint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9503004/14868997), otherwise it will not hold the lock til the end of the transaction, *irrespective* of [any other hints, including `XLOCK`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609217/sql-server-the-misleading-xlock-optimizations).

But you could just do it all in a single statement, here no `UPDLOCK` is needed, and no explicit transaction (the statement runs in a transaction anyway)

```sql
UPDATE TOP (1) q
    SET BQ_status = 'Loading'
    OUTPUT inserted.Id, inserted.GCS_path, inserted.file_first_upload
FROM dbo.[Queue] AS q WITH (SERIALIZABLE, ROWLOCK)
    WHERE q.[BQ_status] IS NULL and q.upload_date IS NOT NULL;
```

While it is true that `SERIALIZABLE` sometimes only take a shared `S` lock, this is *only* true for either `SELECT`, or non-modified joined tables in DML statements.

In this instance, since `Queue` is the table being modified, a `U` lock is taken while finding the right row, this forbids `U` locks from other transactions, which would be blocked waiting (a transaction doing just `SELECT` would not be blocked). Then, when a row is about to be modified, the `U` lock is upgraded to `X`, and is modified.

So there is no fear of race conditions here, nor is the `UPDLOCK` hint necessary either.

Comment: Thanks. That works. But As far as I know, Serializable creates a Shared lock, so other process can still read the row, or am I wrong? I think that to avoid a race condition, the lock should be an exclusive lock and not a shared lock.

Comment: No that's only true for non-modified tables, otherwise a `U` lock is taken which will block other modifiers. You cannot force an `X` lock unless the table is being modified. Have clarified.