# MS SQL Server lock all records where column X = y

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm working with a legacy table which I cannot change. It looks similar to:

```
CREATE TABLE foo 
(
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1) not null,
    OwnerId int not null,
    OwnerRecordId int not null,
    SomeColumn varchra(50) not null,

    CONSTRAINT ix_foo_OwnerId (OwnerId)

    -- Ideally the following constraint would exist, but it doesn't. It is enforced
    -- with code alone. There are currently duplicates, which should not
    -- not exist, but they prevent creation of the unique index.
    --CONSTRAINT ux_foo UNIQUE (OwnerId, OwnerRecordId)
)
```

`OwnerRecordId` is similar to an identity column within each OwnerId:

| Id | OwnerId | OwnerRecordId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 16 | 1 |
| 2 | 16 | 2 |
| 3 | 16 | 3 |
| 4 | 57 | 1 |

Now I would like to copy all records from ownerId 16 to ownerId 57. So OwnerId 57 would end up with 3 new records, and their OwnerRecordId would range from 2 - 4.

While this copying is taking places, other processes might be creating new records.

I thought about doing the following, but the sub-query seems slow:

```
insert into foo (OwnerId, SomeColumn, OwnerRecordId)
    select   
        (57, SomeColumn, (select isnull(max(OwnerRecordId), 0) + 1 
                          from foo where ownerId = 57)
    from foo
    where OwnerId = 16
```

Then I thought I could lock the table where OwnerId = 57. If I could do this I could lock those records, get the current maximum, and then use `ROW_NUMBER` in my select and add that to the MAX value I grabbed once.

Only, I can't seem to prevent other users from selecting from the table short of a table lock. Is there a way to lock records where colun OwnerId = 57? Doing so would prevent others from geting the current max(OwnerRecordId) + 1 value.

Perhas there is a better approach?

Certainly the unique index should be added, I can't do that at this point though.

Comment: If you have no indexes (including constraint indexes), row-level locking is not possible.

Comment: @DanGuzman There is an index on OwnerId. I've added that to my question.

Comment: I think maybe doing declare currentMax int = (select isnull(max(OwnerRecordId), 0) + 1 from foo WITH (ROWLOCK, XLOCK) where OwnerId=57)   would then let me do what I need? Then I could do my insert into and add ROW_NUMBER to to currentMax to get the new  OwnerRecordId value to insert?

Answer (score 0):

The following code should hopefully do the correct amount of locking

```sql
insert into foo WITH (SERIALIZABLE)
    (OwnerId, SomeColumn, OwnerRecordId)
select
  57,
  SomeColumn,
  (select isnull(max(OwnerRecordId), 0) + 1
   from foo with (SERIALIZABLE, UPDLOCK)
   where ownerId = 57)
from foo
where OwnerId = 16;
```

`SERIALIZABLE` (which is a synonym for `HOLDLOCK`) will cause a range lock over all the rows `where ownerId = 57`, and `UPDLOCK` will cause that lock to be held until the end of the  transaction.

You need an index on `(OwnerId)` with `OwnerRecordId` as another key column or as an `INCLUDE`, otherwise the whole table will get locked.

Do not fall into the trap of using `XLOCK`, it [doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4609384/14868997) unless you are actually modifying that table reference.

---

You say you have many different IDs to copy, in which case it would be more performant to do it in bulk.

Dump the list into a temp table (or a Table Valued Parameter), then do a joined update. Something like this

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (SourceId int, TargetId int, primary key (SourceId, TargetId))

-- insert using statements or BULK INSERT or SqlBulkCopy etc

insert into foo WITH (SERIALIZABLE)
    (OwnerId, SomeColumn, OwnerRecordId)
select
  t.TargetId,
  f.SomeColumn,
  ISNULL(f2.mx, 0) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY f.OwnerId ORDER BY f.OwnerRecordId)
FROM foo f
JOIN #tmp t ON t.SourceId = f.OwnerId
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT f2.OwnerId, mx = MAX(f2.OwnerRecordId)
    FROM foo f2 WITH (SERIALIZABLE, UPDLOCK)
    GROUP BY f2.OwnerId
) f2 ON f2.OwnerId = t.TargetId;
```

Comment: The link you gave is above my head, I'm not a DBA. I have multiple queries to run (I run them from C# in more than one statement), and don't want any user to edit/select/insert any record where OwnerId=57 until I release a lock. Is this possible? The problem with the query you propose is that the sub-query is very slow, and I have hundreds of thousands of records to insert.

Comment: This code should work in terms of locking, although it may not be the most efficient for you if done in a loop. Sounds like you should be doing something in bulk, can you describe your use case better? What does "multiple queries" mean? Are you doing many different `OwnerId` in bulk? What are the indexes on the table? Please also share a query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: Yes, possibly hundreds of different OwnerIds, which have a non-clustered index. Hundreds of distinct OwnerId, and each might have upwards of about a million records.

Comment: OK given you a solution for that also. Ensure you have the index, as I said